# PHP - How to tell current session id to the next server request?

Tags: php, apache, http, session, server

I'm having a big trouble here: In my company we have a huge system and too many people access it every day. We are having the following problem:

1. User access his account on the pc A.
2. He goes to write his text
3. He write all his text but doesn't save it. Then open a new tab.
4. In the new tab, he access the account of his customer.
5. Using the account of his customer, he goes to write the customer's text.
6. After type the customer's text, he goes to the previous tab to save his own text and after save the customer text.
7. The two texts appears on the customer's page.

I was thinking in a way of the current screen store somewhere the actual session id, and then when the user click in a link, or post a form, the current page send the session id loaded when it was rendered to the requested page.

Can you help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: The session ID probably doesn't change. It's the content _in_ the session that changes (for example, information about the logged in user). Even with [session_destroy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), the cookie is not unset.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little difficult to follow the use case specified, but it sounds like you need to check access rights to save 'text' to a particular account.

at the moment it appears that your authenticated customer account is saving to an account that isnt theirs?

for eg, in the new text method, before anything happens:

```
if($currentUserID != $accountOwnerID)
{
     // throw a 403 exception here
}
```

this way if they happen to change identity during a session, their access rights will always be checked before anything else can happen.

Comment: Don't forget to output the text on the 403 page. Otherwise, everything the user typed in is lost. But if you output it, he can copy it, login on his other account, and paste it there.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use named sessions. See: [session_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)

By using it, you can have different (and isolated) sessions which will not conflict to each other, even if in the same computer, same browser.

For your particular case, I would create a session named after the user logon, which is unique. That way, if user A logs in, he will have his own session. If a new tab is opened, and he logs as user B, a different session will be created, and both tabs will work simultaneously and correctly, each on it's own session space.

Just add `session_name($UserLogon);` before `session_start()`, should work good.

Comment: This looks great, but how will I know what is the $UserLogon before session_start() ??

Comment: If this is an issue, you can just use a random and unique token, doesn't matter, it just have to be a unique name. Try a md5() on current timestamp. Anyway, this is just the basic idea, the exact implementation is up to you.

Comment: I'm having some troubles to do it, because my code on the LOGIN PAGE is in this way:
 1. Start a session with the given name
 2. Put the loggedUser code in a session variable
 3. Redirect to the user's dashboard.

In the user's dashboard and all other page of the system, the code is:
 1. Start the session (what name I use here?)
 2. Get the user code from the session variable
 3. Instanciate an object from the code
 4. Show the user name.

The problem is on the others page, when I start the session, I'm not getting the name setted on the LOGIN PAGE.

Comment: Indeed, I understand your point. My suggestion is good when you have some unique ID "accessible" before the session set up, and it must be consistent accross pages. I did use this solution in the past, but for different pages, not for different users. The page URLs (used to setup the named sessions) were easy to get before any session setup. I'll think about a workaround and post it here as soon as possible!

Comment: But thank you very much for a new way to think. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use session keys to check.

For that first you need to create a random session key and store it in a session variable. Also provide this value as a hidden element in your form. During the insertion you can check whether the value in hidden element is same as the session key, then insert. Else through error message. After successful insertion reset the session key again. It will overcome your problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good Idea, but the system I work in has about 300 forms and some others 200 ajax posts. I would like an easier way to do it.

Comment: I think you are using some common files like header and footer. In that if there is session then generate a ajax request to the server along with the time of session created as a query string for every 30 sec. If it matches with current session created time in server leave it. Other wise redirect using jquery. It will be the simplest option in your case.